# Is it possible to get multiple values from an Ignite cache by their keys, applying additional filtering server-side, in one operation?

Tags: java, ignite

I have an Ignite cache:

```
IgniteCache<String, Record> cache;
```

A collection of keys of this cache is given. I need to do the following:

1. Get records with the specified keys
2. ... but additionally filter them by some logic defined dynamically (like 'where field `name` has value `John`')
3. ... do it as fast as possible
4. ... under a transaction

One way I tried was using `getAll()` method and applying filtering on my side:

```
cache.getAll(keys).values().stream()
        .filter(... filter logic...)
        .collect(toList());
```

This works, but if the additional filter has high selectivity (i.e. it rejects a lot of data), we'll waste a lot of time on sending unneeded data via network.

Another option is using a scan:

```
cache.query(new ScanQuery<>(new IsKeyIn(keys).and(new CustomFilter())))
```

This makes all the filtering work at the server nodes side, but it is a full scan, and if there are many entries in the cache, while the input keys only constitute a small fraction of it, a lot of time is wasted again, this time on the unneeded scanning.

And there is `invokeAll()` which allows to filter on the server nodes side:

```
cache.invokeAll(new TreeSet<>(keys), new AdditionalFilter())
        .values().stream()
        .map(EntryProcessorResult::get)
        .collect(toList());
```

where

```
private static class AdditionalFilter implements CacheEntryProcessor<String, Record, Record> {
    @Override
    public Record process(MutableEntry<String, Record> entry,
            Object... arguments) throws EntryProcessorException {
        if (... record matches the filter ...) {
            return entry.getValue();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

It finds entries by their keys, it executes filtering logic at server nodes side, but on my data it is even slower than the scanning solution. I suppose (but not sure) this is due to `invokeAll()` being possibly an updating operation, so (according to its Javadoc) it takes locks on the corresponding keys.

I would like to have ability to find entries by given keys, apply additional filtering at the server nodes side and not pay for additional locks (as in my case it's a read-only operation).

Is it possible?

My cache is distributed among 3 server nodes, and its atomicity is `TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT`. The reads are done under transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. SQL is the simplest solution, and possibly the fastest, given proper indexes.
2. `IgniteCompute#broadcast` + `IgniteCache#localPeek`:

```
Collection<Key> keys = ...;
Collection<Collection<Value>> results = compute.broadcast(new LocalGetter(), keys);

...

    class LocalGetter implements IgniteClosure<Collection<Key>, Collection<Value>>
    {
        @Override public Collection<Value> apply(Collection<Key> keys) {
            IgniteCache<Key, Value> cache = ...;

            Collection<Value> res = new ArrayList<>(keys.size());
            
            for (Key key : keys) {
                Value val = cache.localPeek(key, CachePeekMode.PRIMARY);
                
                if (val != null && filterMatches(val)) {
                    res.add(val);
                }
            }
            
            return res;
        }
    }
```

This way we retrieve cache entries efficiently by key, then apply the filter locally, and only send matching entries back over the network. There are only N network calls, where N is the number of server nodes.

Comment: Thank you Pavel! Will this broadcast+localPeek scenario respect transactions? I mean, I need to start a transaction, then make a few rounds of this 'ids->get->filter' operation inside the same transaction and make sure that it is isolated from external modifications (or at least it fails if someone makes a modification externally).

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy sorry I've missed the part about transaction requirements. Unfortunately, neither `Compute` nor `localPeek` participate in transactions.